# Problem in applying DROP Constraint SQL Query on an Attribute of my Table

Tags: sql

Working on a small table Customer_Rental_Report. Its attributes are,

```
Customer_No     VarChar(25),
Customer_Name     VarChar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Customer_Address  VarChar(225),
Customer_Category  VarChar(225),
Category_Description VarChar(25),
Catagory_Discount Float,
Painting_No VarChar(25),
Painting_Title VarChar(50)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Painting_Theme VarChar(225),
Date_of_Hire DATE,
Date_Due_Back DATE,
Returned VarChar(3)
```

what will be the Query for **Dropping Unique constraint** from **Painting Title** attribute

Comment: One question per question.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)